# Kafka nodejs single threaded model - adding consumers

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, consumer

I have developed a Java based Kafka consumer where I have 100 threads for each consumer instance and when the consumption process starts, each thread gets a partition (since there are 100 partitions) and the consumption is done.

I am planning to switch to nodejs and using kafka-node as the client library and I am consuming the topic as described below:

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
var HighLevelConsumer = kafka.HighLevelConsumer;
var Client = kafka.Client;
var client = new Client('xx.xx.xx.xxx:6080');
var topics = [ { topic: "test_1" }];


var options = {
    groupId: 'group1',
    autoCommit: true,
    autoCommitMsgCount: 100,
    autoCommitIntervalMs: 5000,
    fetchMaxWaitMs: 100,
    fetchMinBytes: 1,
    fetchMaxBytes: 1024 * 10,
    fromOffset: false,
    fromBeginning: false
};

var consumer = new HighLevelConsumer(client, topics, options);

consumer.on('message', function (message) {
        console.log(message);
    });

    consumer.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('error', err);
    });
}
```

But the problem here is this is only one consumer. But if I add multiple nodejs processes, I could accomplish 100 consumers but adding each consumer is a rebalancing operation which is costly.

I would like to know whether this is the correct approach ? Is there a way to trigger a 100 threaded consumer using kafka-node?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use supervisor to run your node js code. In supervisor configuration you can specify no of instances(100 in your case) you need to run.

configuration path is: `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/`